# Getting Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggestions',
    aliases: ['suggest'],
    execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
        let channel = message.guild.channel.cache.find(ch=>ch.id==='890313569260937247')
        if(!channel) return message.channel.send({ content: 'There is no suggestion channel on this Server!' });

        let messageArgs = args.join(' ')
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#008000')
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
        .setDescription(messageArgs)
        .setTitle(`${message.author.tag} has a suggestion!!`)

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    }
}
```

I'm basically creating a command with my command Handler, doing a suggestion command, where the arguments of an user are going to be sent in a MessageEmbed.

If I run the actual command, this error shows up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
    at Object.execute (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\commands\suggestions.js:5:37)
    at module.exports (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\events\guild\message.js:11:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:18)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Programming\Workspaces\Discord Bots\Mita Bot v1\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
```

Comment: `guild` is an optional property of [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild): `The guild the message was sent in (if in a guild channel)` so this indicates that the message you are logging at was not send in a guild channel.

Answer (score 1):

As [t.niese said in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306316/getting-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-channels-of-undefined#comment122497024_69306316), [`Message#guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) can be `null`. If `message.guild === null`, this means the message was sent in a DM.

Check if the message was sent in a guild first:

```js
if (!message.guild)
  return message.channel.send('This command can only be used in a server!')

const channel = message.guild.channels.get('890313569260937247')
if (!channel)
  return message.channel.send('There is no suggestion channel on this Server!')
```

Some other points:

- There is no `channel` property on `Guild`; use [`channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) instead.
- You can use [`Collection#get`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) to get a channel by its id (no need to use `.find(c => c.id === someId)`.
- You can use a string directly in [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send): `channel.send('the message')` instead of `channel.send({ content: 'the message' })`.

Answer (score 0):

'channel' is not a property of the Guild class, you probably meant [Guild#channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) which returns the necessary type of GuildChannelManager.